# Anyone knows GCP Composer non-trivial cinit error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, memory, google-cloud-composer

I continuously got the following issues in GCP Composer worker logs. These errors came from different DAGs. Anyone knows what caused the issue?

File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 161, in deepcopy    rv = reductor(4)  File "stringsource", line 2, in grpc._cython.cygrpc.Channel.__reduce_cython__TypeError: no default **reduce** due to non-trivial **cinit**"

Actually, I did not find any errors in Composer Web UI, and tasked were finished successfully. But I am worried about these errors could cause potential problems.

I read the source code of airflow and python, but got no clue what happened there.

I checked the Composer cpu memory disk usage. They are pretty low.

I guess it might be something about Composer worker switching, but not sure. I checked the Composer monitor. I always have 3 workers running. The errors usually happens when a lot of tasks running in 2-3 minutes. If anyone knows the reason, and how to avoid that?